# Select all columns from one table and some from another table

Tags: sql

How do you select all the columns from one table and just some columns from another table using JOIN? In SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*, B.column1, B.column2
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.column3
```